# local storage see how much space each domain is using

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

After going through specification on HTML5 Storage: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/webstorage.html#event-storage

In the paragraph **11.3 Disk space** I have read that

> User agents should allow users to see how much space each domain is
>   using.

But there is no information on how I can do this.

The only solution I came up with - is a hack like this:

```
JSON.stringify(localStorage).length
```

Is there a normal way to do it, because in my case you can see just one domain, not each domain.

Comment: They should show this information to the user, not to the application. You can mostly see it where you can clear the storage, somewhere in the settings. Example: http://help.opera.com/Windows/12.00/en/storage.html

Comment: Seems like you can't do that in Chrome without the use of an extension - you can only delete the web storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An no one gave any response, I will be additing my own answer with whatever information I will find.

`JSON.stringify(localStorage).length` approximate number works for every browser

**IE:**
can be used through JS: `window.localStorage.remainingSpace`

**Chrome:**
through *Settings>Content Settings>Cookies & Site data*